# How do I save a track to a user's Your Music Library using the spotify-ios SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify

I have an `IBAction` that I want to save the track being played by the user. I have the following code in the class that contains my player:

```
- (IBAction)saveTrackToMyMusic:(id)sender {

    [SPTTrack trackWithURI: [NSURL URLWithString:self.spotifyUrl] accessToken:self.session.accessToken market:nil callback:^(NSError *error,SPTTrack *track){

            [self.tracksArray addObject:track];
            [SPTUser requestCurrentUserWithAccessToken:self.session.accessToken callback:^(NSError *error, SPTUser *object) {

                [SPTYourMusic saveTracks:self.tracksArray forUserWithAccessToken:self.session.accessToken callback:^(NSError *error, id object) {
                    if(error){
                        NSLog(@"%@%@",@"Error Saving Track: ",error);
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"Track Saved!");
                    }
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

My `session` is valid, and the SPTTrack object `track` I'm adding to `self.tracksArray` is indeed the correct track. The method runs with no error, but the track is never saved to my music library. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/363 ?

Comment: @Koen, looks like that did the trick! I was adding permissions in the wrong place.

Comment: @AustinBerenyi could you please explain where you went wrong with permissions here? I'm implementing this myself and was curious.